# Как изменить JSP на XHTML в WebApplication в IDEA

Tags: jsp, jsf, java

Доброго всем времени. Может кому вопрос кривым покажется, но мне нужно следующее:

Есть многомодульный проект, который я собираю Maven-ом. Так вот один модуль у меня содержит webapp с web.xml и index.jsp. Так вот мне нужно изменить JSP на JSF. Я добавил в META-INF face-config.xml и заменил index.jsp на index.html (соответственно изменив содержимое).

Задеплоил, и попытался зайти как прежде по `localhost:8080/web`. В результате получил 404.

Я в JSP/JSF не силен, просто где-то прочел, что нужно использовать последний. Вот хотелось попробовать последний. Как сделать?

P.S. как кстати изменить стандартный путь расположения дескриптора web.xml и прочей META-INF и index.jsp? Читал про плагин мавеновский, где в конфиге можно прописать путь, да не получилось =(

Comment: > P.S. как кстати изменить стандартный путь расположения дескриптора web.xml и прочей META-INF

Согласно спецификации web.xml должен лежать в WEB-INF, иначе ваш контейнер не найдет его и не сможет задеплоить.

Comment: Нет, я тут с Вами согласен. Я имею в виду изменить путь, который ведет к META-INF: не src->main->java->webapp, а к примеру src->resources->webapp.

и кстати, не по теме, нет ли пример быстрого создания в HTML странички (button + edit. нажимаем на button - выскакивает диалог загрузки файла, после выбора, весь путь + имя файла грузится в edit)? Буду очень признателен

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно менять почти всё через контекст приложения, например, если в корень (если нет, то имя не **ROOT** имя должно быть) мапить хотим:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/ROOT.xml

<Context>

    <Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext" 
extraResourcePaths="/WEB-INF=/my/pathw/web/WEB-INF,/WEB-INF/classes=/my/path/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/,/pages=/my/path/web/" />

    <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader" virtualClasspath="/my/path/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/;/my/path/lib/*.jar"/>

</Context>
```

Это удобно для настройки на папку разработки, чтобы постоянно разворачивать не приходилось. Class-файлы понятно перегружаться в общем случае не будут (без какого-нибудь jrebel), но на JSP изменения будут видны моментально.

Comment: Насколько это переносимо на другие контейнеры и сервера?

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, простите, я с jboss познакомился только месяца полтора назад, и то в режиме - вот книга на англ. по ejb, приходи через 3 дня и расскажи, что понял... это я к чему... catalina - это, насколько помогает мне интуиция, это tomcat? я хотел спросить, можно ли как-нить настроить пути в pom-нике, чтобы привязка была к определенному проекту, т.е. к его pom.xml... или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: pom-ник описывает только сборку и к исполнению приложения не имеет отношения.

Comment: Да, да! Я ошибся. У меня вопрос в другом - я хотел persistence.xml положить по определенной директории при сборке.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html - тут указан плагин, в конфиге которого можно прописать путь к персистенс. Но у меня не сработал. А сам сервер (не знаю точно какой его компонент) получается по умолчанию лезет по определенному пути в war-нике и ищет web.xml. Так?

Comment: @Nofate думаю, только для tomcat работать будет.

@nightin_gale, Вам нужно положить *persistence.xml* в /src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml, тогда maven присборке .war файла положит его в WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xm

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, извиняюсь за занудство, но суть вопроса не в том, куда его положить) я знаю куда) но я хочу положить в произвольный путь: произвольный_путь/META-INF/persistence.xml - типа вот так. и чтобы maven мне вот в такой конфигурации его собрал. понимаете?

Comment: @nightin_gale, maven за жесткую структуру проекта как раз и не любят.
Думаю проблему можно [решить][1], но когда возникают такие задачи лучше сразу перейти на Gradle.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799573/making-maven-do-file-copying-between-building-and-running